# How to deal with Nulls in LINQ expressions?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I am wanting to know the best way for the following expression to return null if the "Orders" collection is null. Currently "First" raises an exception. I have tried "FirstOrDefault" without success.

The expression:

```
var myOrderItems = Model.Orders.First(o => o.Id == 1).OrderItems.ToList();
```

If there are no Orders then I would like "myOrderItems" to just be null.

This is an example query since I would want to apply the recommended answer to other queries.

EDIT: I currently define "Orders" in the ViewModel as:

```
List<Orders> _myOrders;
```

Possibly it should be defined as:

```
List<Orders> _myOrders = new List<Orders> or something else to make it empty???????
```

Comment: When you say "no orders", do you mean that `Model.Orders` will actually be `null`, or will it be an empty collection? It would help to know which exception you got.

Comment: A general tip as well, it is usually much more useful to return empty collections rather than `null`, as it simplifies code all over the place since you don't have to keep checking for `null` everywhere.

Comment: Yes Model.Orders are null in that "Orders" comes from a ViewModel and sometimes it is not initialised. When you say empty how do you recommend I set the collection to be empty ie: private List<Feature> _myFeatures = ??

Comment: Perhaps it would be a good idea to set a default of "empty" in my VM to these collections so that if they do not get set then they will be empty by default. Is this correct?

Comment: @SamJolly Why aren't they set?

Comment: In the View Model when it gets instantiated, although at times some of these properties may not have values, it the List<T> may be not populated therefore at present it is null. See comment against your answer below about best approach for defining empty default values. Thanks

Comment: If `null` means something other than an empty collection I would rather use an empty collection, ie. `Orders = new List<Order>();` than `null` because the rest of the code becomes much easier to deal with if you take the problem with `null`-references out of the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var myOrderItems = Model.Orders == null ? null : Model.Orders.First(o => o.Id == 1).OrderItems.ToList();
```

Comment: That doesn't do what the OP wants, apart from checking if Model.Orders is null. He doesn't want an exception if there is nothing with an Id of 1.

Comment: He wrote **If there are no Orders**,
not **If there are no Orders *with ID = 1***

Comment: OK this "null ? null" tip is useful to know.

Comment: @SamJolly That's a conditional operator: syntax is `condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false`. There is also a binary coalesce operator: syntax is `value ?? other_value` and it means *take value if it's not null, otherwise take other_value*

Comment: And there are also VB equivalents: `If(condition, value_if_true, value_if_false)` for the conditional one, `If(value, other_value)` for the coalesce one.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var myOrderItems = ((Model.Orders ?? Enumerable.Empty<YourType>())
                       .FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == 1) ?? SomeNonNullDefault).OrderItems.ToList();
```

Add an `AsQueryable` after `Enumerable.Empty` if you're using `IQueryable` and not `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Thanks, interesting approach. I think this raises the question as to whether coping with nulls should be dealt with in the VM or in the LINQ expression with the testing of Null via ?? etc.

Comment: Interesting approach, but wont this throw exception if FirstOrDefault returns null and then .OrderItems is called on it?

Comment: I am now wondering whether I should set the original property in the ViewModel with an appropriate default value, possibly "Empty" whereby any using LINQ will not crash. Not totally clear on how I define the default for the List<T> property yet and whether it will prevent my LINQ crashes.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<OrderItems> myOrderItems = null;
if (Model.Orders != null)
{
    var order = Model.Orders.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == 1);

    if (order != null)
    {
        myOrderItems = order.OrderItems.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: If `Orders` is `null`, this will still throw an exception.

Comment: Missed the _"Orders" collection is null_. Probably because it's a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

> If there are no `Order`s then I would like `myOrderItems` to just be `null`.

That's the wrong way to approach this. If there are no `Order`s, then `Order`s should return an empty collection, but **not `null`**. If possible, fix that. In any case, don't repeat the same mistake with `myOrderItems`.

Comment: Since this is coming from a ViewModel, then should I set a default for the type when defined. See EDIT above. I have raised a question about how to default the Orders List property to empty in the VM. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @SamJolly That depends on what exactly does it mean. An empty list should be represented by an empty `List`. List that doesn't have a value (yet) should be represented by `null`.